# Zabbix. Why on two same linux servers, with the same configuration and same template, I have different items and triggers on zabbix server?

Tags: linux, zabbix

I set up two same servers with the same configuration. I link with hosts the same templates on the Zabbix server, but Hosts has different counts items, triggers, and graphs, why?

Comment: Because of discoveries probably. You might need to add details or screenshot to describe your question better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the no. of services, filesystems, processes etc discovered by the descovery templates. so, the no. of items and triggers will not be the same. Here is the documentation

https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/devel/en/manual/web_interface/frontend_sections/configuration/templates

https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/devel/en/manual/web_interface/frontend_sections/configuration/templates/items

https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/devel/en/manual/web_interface/frontend_sections/configuration/templates/triggers

https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/devel/en/manual/web_interface/frontend_sections/configuration/templates/discovery